# Is it ok to make an independent clause into a dependent one with a gerund verb?

Tags: grammar, gerund-phrases

I see this particular sentence structure all the time when reading fiction,
and it bothers me. I most often see it in between dialogue tags.

1. She whispered, her hair blowing in the wind.

It’s always an independent clause followed by [subject][gerund
verb][object/last part of sentence]. I think it’s grammatically incorrect
and that it would look better as [independent clause].[separate sentence].:

2. She whispered. Her hair blew in the wind.

Or as [independent clause] as [independent clause].:

3. She whispered as her hair blew in the wind.

Or if the second subject was actually the same as the first, one could do:

4. She whispered, blowing wind through her hair.

I know that the lattermost three examples are grammatically correct, but is
the first example grammatically correct? Is it grammatically correct to use
[independent clause], [subject][gerund verb][object/last part of sentence]?

Comment: You can do that, and it is grammatical, but it sounds incomplete, which it wouldn't if the verb were different: *She stood there, her hair blowing in the wind.* Or if the verb were the same, but there were more to it: *She whispered, her hair blowing in the wind, "I will always love you."*

Comment: @Robusto I think the OP meant “she whispered” follows a dialogue fragment.

Comment: @StephenS: That is what I was responding to. In both of my examples the original fragment is left intact.

Comment: @Robusto I mean: “I’m cold,” she whispered, her hair ...

Comment: As @Greybeard shows below, your rewrite, "She whispered as (while) her hair blew in the wind," does match the original meaning closely.

Answer (score 1):

> 1. She whispered, her hair blowing in the wind.

is not the same as

> 2. She whispered. Her hair blew in the wind.

The difference lies in the simple form and the continuous form of the verb (or any other “-ing” form)

The simple form indicates an act as a whole; the continuous form indicates an action that was, at the time referred to, incomplete.

The combination of the simple form and the continuous form allows simultaneous actions:

1. She whispered, her hair blowing in the wind. -> She whispered (while/and at the same time) her hair blew/was blowing in the wind.
2. She whispered. Her hair blew in the wind. -> She whispered. She stopped whispering, and then her hair blew in the wind.